# How to show one Control beside another Control dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

There is a class `NodeButton`, and these `NodeButton`'s are being created dynamically and then added to `Parent Control` which is `Panel`.
In the `NodeButton` there is created an inside `TextBox` and it shows correctly over the `NodeButton`.
**The problem is that I need to create another inside `TextBox`, which should be located on the right side of the `NodeButton`.** As the `Button` can be `Moved`, the `TextBox` should move too like the first one. Now the new `TextBox` is not visible as it is outside the `Button`'s borders.
Is this possible without creating Wrapper Control for the button and TextBox, the NodeButton class is too complicated..

```
+------+ +-------+
|Button| |TextBox|
+------+ +-------+

public class NodeButton : Button
{
  ...
  public NodeButton()
  {
    TextBox tb = new TextBox()
    {
       Name = ...
       Location = New Point(2,2);
       ...
       Parent = this;
    }
    this.Controls.Add(tb);    

  ..
  }
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.Controls.Add(tb);
```

Don't add the textbox to the button's Controls collection, add it to the button's Parent.  Roughly:

```
tb.Location = new Point(this.Right + 5, this.Top);
this.Parent.Controls.Add(tb);
```

Do make sure that the Parent is valid, it isn't clear that it might be from the context.  If not, or you can't be sure, then overriding OnParentChanged is best.  Using a UserControl could be advisable.  So is not cramming panels full of controls, that tends to grind your UI to a crawl.

Comment: This draws the `TextBox` as needed :) but when I drag and drop the `NodeButton` the TextBox does not move.
Do I have to write my own code to move it with `NodeButton` in the moving event handlers? I don't want to do that because I need at least 3 textboxes and 3 labels around that `NodeButton`

Comment: You would also need to override OnLocationChanged() so you can move the text box as well.  Arbitrarily increasing the number of controls makes a UserControl the clearly superior approach.

Comment: Wow, `OnLocationChanged()` helped. Thank You!
I will use the `UserControl` as the base class :)